# Sending an array with compact to the view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an array like this:

```
$currentSelection = array('category' => $request->category, 'location' => $request->location);
```

When I send this to view like this:

```
return view('index', compact('currentSelection'));
```

I get this message:

> undefined variable currentSelection

How can I send the array properly with compact()?

Comment: Are you sure `$currentSelection` is defined in scope somewhere? [`compact` will not issue warnings if it doesn't exist](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php), so likely your underlying `view` function is choking.

Comment: @Mark you were right, it was indeed a scope problem. How do I close this question?

Comment: I have gone ahead and flagged it. Glad you solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return view('index')->with(compact('currentSelection'));
```

or

```
return view('index', array('currentSelection' => $currentSelection)); // the second param is an array, you can pass multiple elements in this array
```

and you can access its value on view blade view like:

```
{{ $currentSelection }}
```

**Note:** In your case `$currentSelection` is an `array`, so you have to use `foreach()` to get its all element

Comment: I have few other objects too, containing the results returned from Laravels Eloquent Models, for simplicity's sake I ignored them here.

I would like to send them along with the $currentSelection without using with() method, and using compact() only, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return view('index', compact($currentSelection));
```

As per Eisenheim comment:

edited to be

```
return view('index', compact('varname', $currentSelection));
```

Comment: Doesn't work when I add another variable, like this:

return view('index', compact('myNewVar', $currentSelection));

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this:

```
return view('index', compact(['currentSelection']));
```

Comment: Inside the array syntax?  Did you test this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
return view('index', [
   'currentSelection' => $currentSelection,
]);
```

Hope this work for you!